# Is $ \{ \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{m} : n,m \in \mathbb{N} \}$ dense in some interval of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, real-analysis

Consider the set $\{\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{m}: n,m \in \mathbb{N} \}$. Is this set dense in some interval of $\mathbb{R}$?

More generally let $S_k= \{\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{n_i}: n_i \in \mathbb{N} \} $. Is this set dense in some interval of $\mathbb{R}$?

I think the answer to both questions is no, but I was not able to come up with a proof. I am a physics student so I apologise if this question is naive for this website.

Comment: How can this set be dense in $\mathbb R$, if all finite elements are $\le2$ ?

Comment: On [math.se], you can find [several posts](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%20%5C%7B%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%7D%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bm%7D%20%3A%20n%2Cm%20%5Cin%20%5Cmathbb%7BN%7D%20%5C%7D%24%2C%20closure&p=1) which are about finding closure (or limit points) of this set. For example: [Find the limit points of the set $\{ \frac{1}{n} +\frac{1}{m} \mid n , m = 1,2,3,\dots \}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/930646) and the [posts linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/930646).

Comment: Sorry, I agree the title did not make sense, but I changed it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

We may assume $n\le m$ throughout.

Let $y>x>0$. There are only finitely many $n$ with
$$
1/n\ge x/2.
$$
For each such $n$, the set of $1/n+1/m$ as $m$ varies is not dense in any subinterval of $(x,y)$.

A finite union of sets not dense in any subinterval of $(x,y)$ is still not dense in any subinterval of $(x,y)$, since you can "escape" the sets one at a time.

Hence your set is not dense in $(x,y)$.

Comment: The same argument shows that for any sequences $(u_n),(v_n)$ tending to zero (and with infinite image), the only limit points of $\{u_n+v_m,n,m\ge 0\}$ are $\{0\}\cup\{u_n:n\ge 0\}\cup\{v_n:n\ge 0\}$ (and same for finitely many sequences).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. Because any convergent sequence of elements of $S_k$ has rational limit. Let $s_p$ be such a sequence. Then we have sequence $q_p=(n_{1p};\dots;n_{kp})\in\mathbb{N}^k$ such that $s_p=\sum_i \frac{1}{n_{ip}}$. Let $T=\{i_1;\dots;i_r\}$  is the set of indices such that the sequence $\{n_{i_kp}\}_{p\in\mathbb{N}}$ is stationary beginning from some $p_{i_k}$. Then 
$$
\lim_{p\to\infty}s_p = \begin{cases}
\sum\limits_{i\in T}\frac{1}{n_{ip_{i}}},~\text{if}~~ T\neq\emptyset \\
0,~\text{if}~~ T=\emptyset
\end{cases}
$$